# c++ vector: segfault on insert

Tags: vector, insert, segmentation-fault

The folowing code is giving a segfault when reaching the insert statement:

```
rna* annealer::anneal(rna strand1, rna strand2, const rna & opponent){

 std::vector<nukleotid*>::iterator sit2;
 std::vector<nukleotid*>::iterator eit2;
 std::vector<nukleotid*>::iterator eit;

 if(tryAnneal(strand1, strand2, opponent)) {
  eit = strand1.getStrand().end();
  sit2 = strand2.getStrand().begin();
  eit2 = strand2.getStrand().end();

         //here be segfault
  strand1.getStrand().insert(eit, sit2, eit2);
  strand1.isAnnealed = true;
  rna* str = &strand1;
  std::cout << *str << std::endl;
  return str;
 }


    //...

 return NULL;
}
```

rna contains a vector, which is returned by getStrand().

Its driving me crazy. I really cant understand why theres a segfault. A slightly different version of the code, in which in didnt declare new iterators, but was just passing `strand1.getStrand().end();` (and the two other), to vector::insert() derictly threw a length_error which does not make any sense either, as my vectors are small (~10 elements).

can anyone see what am i doing wrong here?`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `getStrand()` returns a `vector` *by value*, then `sit2` and `eit2` are iterators into different copies of the `vector`, and both copies are destroyed as soon as you obtain the iterators.  You need either to return the `vector` *by reference* or save the copy of the `vector` and obtain iterators from that one copy instead.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that getStrand is returning a copy of the vector, instead of a reference to it. That will cause the iterators you're using (eit, sit2, and so on) to become invalid immediately after they're created!

Can you paste your declaration for that method?

Comment: yes, that is indeed the case! my vector is returned by value! thank you very much!